# How can I turn list of proxies into json of proxies

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a list of proxies:

```
proxies = [
  "188.166.78.120:8080",
  "18.210.69.172:3128",
  "178.128.166.50:8118"
]
```

But for a library I need JSON like this:

```
proxies = {
  "http":  "http://188.166.78.120:8080",
  "https": "http://188.166.78.120:8080",
  "http":  "http://18.210.69.172:3128",
  "https": "http://18.210.69.172:3128",
  "http":  "http://178.128.166.50:8118",
  "https": "http://178.128.166.50:8118"
}
```

How can I make that?
I have tried this but I only get last one

```
new = {}

    for i in proxies:
        proxy = {
                "http":"http/"+i,
                "https":"http/"+i
        }
        new.update(proxy)
```

Comment: Your result is technically valid JSON, but most json decoders will not decode it as you might expect; as only one value from duplicate keys will be kept. Are you sure this is the desired output format?

Comment: yes I am I have tried with the first one and It didn't work with second it worked

Comment: Have you tried looping over the list to build an object in the correct format?

Comment: yes but then I only get last entry in list

Comment: Can you show your attempt at that? Questions receive more responses if it's clear their asker has tried to solve the problem themselves first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have to use unique key for python dictionary. You need to use list in dict for multiple value.

Below is solution of your problem

```
import json

proxies = [
  "188.166.78.120:8080",
  "18.210.69.172:3128",
  "178.128.166.50:8118"
]
js = dict()

for i in proxies:
    js.setdefault('http',[])
    js.setdefault('https',[])
    js['http'].append('http://'+i)
    js['https'].append('http://'+i)

x = json.dumps(js)   
y = json.loads(x)
print(js)
print(x)
print(y["http"])
```

python dictionary:

```
{'http': ['http://188.166.78.120:8080',
  'http://18.210.69.172:3128',
  'http://178.128.166.50:8118'],
 'https': ['http://188.166.78.120:8080',
  'http://18.210.69.172:3128',
  'http://178.128.166.50:8118']}
```

json:

```
{"http": ["http://188.166.78.120:8080", "http://18.210.69.172:3128", "http://178.128.166.50:8118"], "https": ["http://188.166.78.120:8080", "http://18.210.69.172:3128", "http://178.128.166.50:8118"]}
```

http list:

```
['http://188.166.78.120:8080', 'http://18.210.69.172:3128', 'http://178.128.166.50:8118']
```

Comment: this is nothing like output I need

Comment: It is not possible that way

Comment: @SayedSohan That is not true. If they indeed want JSON it is of course possible to produce that JSON.

Comment: I know that is possible.. but you can't get expected result with that JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As other users have pointed out, you should avoid using that format if you can because most JSON parsers will consider that as a dictionary and thus keys must be unique.

Here is a way to test this by creating a string with the right format and then encoding it to JSON:

```
import json

proxies = [
  "188.166.78.120:8080",
  "18.210.69.172:3128",
  "178.128.166.50:8118"
]

p = []

p.append('{')

for i, proxy in enumerate(proxies):
    p.append('"http": "http://{0}", "https": "https://{0}"'.format(proxy))
    if not i == len(proxies) - 1:
        p.append(',')

p.append('}')

text_format = ''.join(p)

print (text_format)
```

The output is the format you are looking for:

```
{"http": "http://188.166.78.120:8080", "https": "https://188.166.78.120:8080","http": "http://18.210.69.172:3128", "https": "https://18.210.69.172:3128","http": "http://178.128.166.50:8118", "https": "https://178.128.166.50:8118"}
```

Now let's convert that string into JSON:

```
json_format = json.loads(text_format)

print (json_format)
```

Only the first key is present as it is not allowed to have repeated keys:

```
{'http': 'http://178.128.166.50:8118', 'https': 'https://178.128.166.50:8118'}
```

So you could just use the string generated above or use an alternative valid way to encode this, for example:

```
import json

proxies = [
  "188.166.78.120:8080",
  "18.210.69.172:3128",
  "178.128.166.50:8118"
]

p = [{'http': 'http://{0}'.format(item), 'https': 'https://{0}'.format(item)} for item in proxies]

j = json.dumps(p)

print (j)
```

Output:

```
[{"http": "http://188.166.78.120:8080", "https": "https://188.166.78.120:8080"}, {"http": "http://18.210.69.172:3128", "https": "https://18.210.69.172:3128"}, {"http": "http://178.128.166.50:8118", "https": "https://178.128.166.50:8118"}]
```